# Why id & sessionid in URL?

Tags: url, sessionid, userid

I see some URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?view=profile&id=098&hash=589e8bed895198495d987d055699d2b9
```

Why some sites add ID and hashed password to URL? Is it the session ID?
Is there any advantage with using URL like that for user profiles?

Comment: Without more information, you cannot tell what the extra information is.  Hash may be a variety of things, depending on what the coder is doing.  In this case, ID likely refers to the profile that is being viewed (the target) while the hash may refer to some sort of action or session identifier (likely not a real session id).  However... this is all WILD conjecture without knowing more about the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent is likely to prevent you from quickly stepping through pages with a predictable URL pattern.

If their profile URLs were just like:
http://www.siteadress.com/?view=profile&id=098

you could go to http://www.siteadress.com/?view=profile&id=099, http://www.siteadress.com/?view=profile&id=100, etc. and expect to find content there. If the profiles include, say, e-mail addresses, it'd be a great find for a spambot to crawl through.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this.  The data has to get sent somehow... the site programmers chose this particular method.

It isn't pretty... that's about it.

You should also note that you can set your PHP session ID this way, [depending on configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you disagree, you should add a comment, for everyone's benefit.